# CSV loading and filter creating in Crossfilter / DC.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Charting newbie here.
I have a CSV file which I want to visulise in d3 using crossfilter (dc.js).

I can't seem to get the pie chart .group() to work correctly, I think it might be something to do with either reading in the CSV OR I just don't understand enough about the crossfilter grouping command.

```
 function initDc(data) {
     ndx = crossfilter(data);
     all = ndx.groupAll();
     var chart = dc.pieChart("#summary");
     var region = ndx.dimension(function (d){return d['REGION_NAME'];});

    var conversion =  region.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.TreatProd1;});
  chart
      .width(568)
      .height(580)
   // .slicesCap(4)
      .innerRadius(10)
      .dimension(region)
      .group(conversion) // by default, pie charts will use group.key as the    label
      .renderLabel(true)
     .label(function (d) {
      console.log('label');
      console.log(d);
       return d.key.toUpperCase();
      });
    chart.render();
 }
```

So the log seems to return 'object' rather than the actual region name here is the sample data

```
     REGION_NAME,TreatProd1
     Dublin,0
```

And my read data function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    d3.csv("data/sample_data001.csv", function (data) {
        //d3.csv("data/sample_datav002.csv", function (data) {
            loadVizData(data);
        //}); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is only this line :

```
REGION_NAME,TreatProd1
Dublin,0
```

then the pie has nothing to show (sum is 0).

I have tried with more data :

```
REGION_NAME,TreatProd1
Dublin,1
Dublin2,2
Dublin3,3
```

The pie is correctly shown.

Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/R4tDrG8kRmFKHUEzK1QT?p=preview